# Sharepoint Server

Tags: list, sharepoint

I have customized my New, View & edit forms by using the below URL
http://www.markrackley.net/2013/08/29/easy-custom-layouts-for-default-sharepoint-forms/

My form has 3 input fields as below

Reference number (Text Field)
Start Time (Date Time Field)
End Time (Date Time Field)

Default Form already has default Save & Cancel button

I want to add another button to display current system time in "**Start Time**" field & "**End Time**" field.

Also, one more button will duplicate item and save it as new entry instead of updating on the same ID.

It would be grateful for me if anyone could provide code in Vb or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To duplicate you can create worklfow in spd called copy list item or create list item. Then create workflow actions and add botton in the ribbon. 
Start time can be done using calculated column. Set calculation =(NOW)
And use workflow to set item created time as the end time.

Comment: Thanks Sudnep, unfortunately i do not have access to SPD, is there any otther way to do it programmatically ex:javascript??